# List form send data to excel in Documentlibrary

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, form, flow

Is it possible to send data from a Sharepoint list form to an excel file that is stored in Documentlibrary. If it is possible how should I do it? I couldnt find any tutorial on this matter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export to excel action in your desired list. It will download a query file. Open it and an excel file which has a data connection to your list will be created. Save the excel file and upload it to the library. The work is done.

When there are changes in the excel file, just refresh your data, it will update your workbook data.

Have a check on this article for detailed steps:
https://sharepointmaven.com/export-sharepoint-excel/